# Do $\text{cl}~f$ and $f$ have the same Lipschitz condition?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am reading the book "Convex Analysis" by R.T. Rockafellar. In page.117, 
it said that "the Lipschitz condition is satisfied by $f$ if and only if it is satisfied by $\text{cl}~f$".

I am not sure that I could understand this sentence exactly. 
First, if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, it is obviously continuous and then we have $f = \text{cl}~f$. 
In this situation, $f$ has the same Lipschitz condition with $\text{cl}~f$.

However, if $\text{cl}~f$ is Lipschitz continuous, I think $f$ may not be Lipschitz continuous?
For example, let 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-x}, \quad \text{if}~x > 0, \\
10, \quad \text{if}~x = 0, \\
+\infty, \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Then its closed function $\text{cl}~f$ is 
\begin{equation}
(\text{cl}~f)(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-x}, \quad \text{if}~x \ge 0, \\
+\infty, \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
So the $\text{cl}~f$ is Lipschitz continuous but $f$ is not.

Here the definition of $\text{cl}~f$ is the closure of function $f$, i.e., the largest lower semi-continuous function majorized by $f$.

By the way, maybe there are some additional conditions that $f$ is proper and convex.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of "Lipschitz condition"? I agree that your given $f$ is proper and convex, and $\operatorname{cl} f$ is Lipschitz *on its domain*. Perhaps Rockafellar means $f$ is Lipschitz on the whole space, meaning that $\infty$ cannot be attained anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure the definition of Lipschitz condition. Rockafellar did not provide an exact definition of Lip condition in his book, but the Lipschitz continuous is defined on a given domain. So you mean that it needs a condition that $f$ should be finite everywhere?

Comment: I'm not really sure what Rockerfellar is claiming precisely, but that's my best guess. I would normally say a function $f : X \to \Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz if $|f(x) - f(y)| \le K\|x - y\|$ **for all** $x, y \in X$. This cannot happen if $f(x) = \infty$ for any $x$. (I would also be happy to say a function is Lipschitz on a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ if that inequality held for all $x, y \in \mathcal{U}$.)

Comment: I think you are right, and in my example we can define $X = [0,+\infty)$, and $f(x) \neq \infty$ for any $x \in X$. In this sense, the $\text{cl}~f$ is Lipschitz continuous,  but maybe it still is not Lipschitz continuous for $f$?

Comment: I think maybe we really need the function $f$ is finite everywhere? Because in the boundary of $\text{dom}~f$, the Lipschitz continuous may not hold?

Comment: I was actually thinking of $X$ as the whole linear space. I've always talked about convex functions as being functions from the whole space to $[-\infty, \infty]$, and the "domain" is considered to be the set of $x$ such that $f(x) < \infty$. It seems essential to me that there be finite function values in each direction.

Comment: I have understood what is your definition, in this sense, I think the conclusion is correct. Thank you.